# Why isn't var and let working in react componnent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

My code sandbox says.

```js
 /src/App.js: Unexpected reserved word 'let' (9:4)
    
    export default function App() {
     return (
>       var wow = '1'
         ^
           
       <div className="App">
       <h1>Tensorflow</h1>
```

This is the code.

This line imports react and style file.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
    
export default function App() {
  return (
```

This is the error line

```js
    let wow = '1'
  );
}
```

Comment: Please, follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please do  more research before asking questions in the future.

Comment: Question, why is the ```let wow = '1'``` part now ```let```, and why is it now at the end of the function while in the first code snippet it was at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your information, the var (or let) is not supposed to be there, because you are supposed to be returning just jsx, and you should define the variable outside the return. So, just move the var (or let) statement out of the return statement like so:

```js
export default function App() {
  var wow = '1';
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Tensorflow</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```